# VPC subnet error when deploying Bitname Elasticsearch to non-default GCE network

Tags: google-compute-engine, elasticsearch, bitnami

Deploying Bitnami's single-VM Elasticsearch. The error is:

```
Invalid value for field 'resource.networkInterfaces[0]': ''. Subnetwork should be specified for custom subnetmode network
```

It works fine if I deploy it to my `default` network, but I get this error if I try to deploy it to my `development` network. If I understand it right, it's because they don't let me choose a subnet. Is there any kind of workaround? Can I set a default subnet in my VPC somehow? My development Kubernetes cluster is in that network, so I can't delete it and recreate it, but if there's no better solution I could try to create a `development2` with "automatic subnet creation" and peer them, messy as that is.

(Bitnami support don't accept this as their problem.)

Comment: Hi Dan, Bitnami Engineer here. As we mentioned in the ticket you opened, our team is investigating the issue and will update your ticket and this thread as soon as we have more information.